# Passing by constant reference in the lambda capture list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm building a lambda function that requires access to a fair number of variables in the context.

```
const double defaultAmount = [&]{
    /*ToDo*/
}();
```

I'd rather not use `[=]` in the list as I don't want lots of value copies to be made.

I'm concerned about program stability if I use `[&]` since I don't want the lambda to modify the capture set.

Can I pass by const reference? `[const &]` doesn't work.

Perhaps a good compiler optimises out value copies, so `[=]` is preferable.

Comment: Are these local or member variables? What compiler do you use?

Comment: A bit of both. I'm using MSVC2012, and am supposed to write code that compiles with newer g++.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create and capture const references explicitly:

```
int x = 42;
const int& rx = x;
auto l = [&rx]() {
    x = 5; // error: 'x' is not captured
    rx = 5; // error: assignment of read-only reference 'rx'
};
```

Answer (score 25):

The capture list is limited in what can be captured; basically by-value or by-reference (named or by default), the `this` pointer and nothing.

From the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (snippet);

> The *captures* is a comma-separated list of zero or more captures, optionally beginning with the *capture-default*. The capture list defines the outside variables that are accessible from within the lambda function body. The only capture defaults are;
>
> - **`&`** (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by reference) and
> - **`=`** (implicitly capture the used automatic variables by copy).
>
> The syntax of an individual capture in *captures* is;
>
> - `identifier` simple by-copy capture
> - `& identifier` simple by-reference capture
> - `this` simple by-reference capture of the current object
> - `* this` simple by-copy capture of the current object

You could create local `const&` to all the object you wish to capture and use those in the lambda.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    const int& refa = a;
    const int b = [&]() -> int {
        //refa = 10; // attempts to modify this fail
        return refa;
    }();
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

The capture could be either for all the references, or an explicit list what is required;

```
const int b = [&refa]()
```

Another alternative is not to capture the local variables at all. You then create a lambda that accepts as arguments the variables you need. It may be more effort as the local variable count grows, but you have more control over how the lambda accepts its arguments and is able to use the data.

```
auto lambda = [](const int& refa /*, ...*/) { */...*/ }
lambda(...);
```

Comment: Just a heads up, I don't think cppreference say this anymore. Specifically, isn't [this] captured by reference?

Comment: Thanks, updated the quote to match the current text, semantics remain the same

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the C++11 grammar does not allow for this, so no.

Comment: If the subroutine requires "a fair number of variables in the context," making a proper function and passing them all is probably precisely what the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture a constant reference to an object, not an object itself:

```
A a;
const A& ref_a = a;

const double defaultAmount = [&]{
    ref_a.smth();
}();
```